# spy++ finding button properties like caption, etc

Tags: c++, spy++

I am having difficulties with spy++. I have visual studio 2010 so I don't know if there is a difference between the spy++ of 2010 and 2013 but w/e. So the issue is the following:

I am making a program (program 1) that will click on a button of another program (program 2). Now in order to do that I need to be able to identify the button somehow. I have managed to get the handle for the parent window of program 2 with the FindWindow() function. From there I used the EnumChildWindows() function to go through all the child windows. Now... the issue is the following, I need to find something to Identify my button with when I get to the window it is in.

Question:: How do I use spy++ to find the caption and other properties of a specific button? The finder tool in spy++ only clicks on windows and not buttons, so I have had a hard time finding anyyyy single thing about buttons with spy++.

Comment: _The finder tool in spy++ only clicks on windows and not buttons, so I have had a hard time finding anyyyy single thing about buttons with spy++._ Huh? It finds buttons just fine for me.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010... not sure if that has anything to do with it... could you tell me step by step the buttons you click to find buttons with the finder tool? where do you go to find the finder tool you use?

Comment: I'm using VS2013, so that might be relevant. But I just click the "Find Window" button on the toolbar, then click and drag the little crosshairs over the button I want information for. Then I make sure the "Properties" radiobutton is selected and click "OK", and the Control ID shows up in the properties window that appears.

Comment: I see, well for some reason I am not able to get the button but only the window that the button is in... Near the finder tool there should be a text that says something like: "Drag the Finder Tool over a window to select it.... blah blah..", does it say the same thing to you? cause mine specifies "window"?

Comment: Mine specifies "window" too, but see my comment in your other question: _Buttons are a type of window too, really. Almost every control is. (If it helps, creating buttons requires a call to `CreateWindowEx`.) You can drag the finder tool over a button the same as you can drag it over a window._

Comment: Yeah I saw the comment. Kinda odd, when I place the finder tool over the button, it doesn't select the button but rather the window that the button is in. I am guessing it could be a problem with the properties or something of the spy++ program. Do you by any chance know a function that would show all the buttons or controls a specific window has? If you do, I could use that in the code I already have implemented to possibly find the information I need rather than spy++

Comment: Is your target a standard button, or possibly a custom-drawn one? Try dragging the tool over a button in something like Notepad and see what happens. If you want to experiment with your own code, try running `EnumChildWindows` through the parent window and log all the control IDs somewhere, then experiment with them one by one.

Comment: Not all buttons are actual windows. Custom drawing controls has become quite trendy of late. If that's the case for the one you're interested in, then you're SOL. Before giving up entirely, use the Window Finder to select the parent window, then dig through the window hierarchy looking for the button object of interest.

Comment: A question: The button i am looking for is on a tool bar, does that interfere with spy++ in any way?

Comment: Yes, buttons in a toolbar are not button controls. They're toolbar buttons. Implemented entirely differently. Step 1 is finding out what type of toolbar control you're dealing with. Windows has at least 3 different types built in. And then there's the possibility of third-party libraries. Step 2 is consulting the documentation to see how to programmatically invoke a button on that toolbar. It isn't going to be easy. Aren't you the same person people have repeatedly recommended using UI Automation?

Comment: HAHA yeah I am that person, but I have no idea what UI Automation even is... mind giving me an explanation?